Wrong fonts in vim-airline
I have vim-devicons installed (using vim-plug, and it is before vim-airline). But I don't see correct language glyphs.


Could you tell us what is Vim encoding (:set encoding?)?

Do you have nerd-fonts installed? What is the font Vim use (set guifont?)? What is the font of your running on your terminal if you use a terminal version of Vim?

Maybe the How can I setup a nerdfont in lua answer could be of some help?

I have set encoding=utf-8 and set fileencoding=utf-8.

Oh, I didn't have nerd-fonts installed. Installing it fixed everything. Thanks a lot.

Thanks for the feedback :-) I have tried to gather instructions in an answer. Let me know if I missed something.

In order for vim-devicons to work smooth you need:

Make sure encoding is set to utf-8 (:set encoding=utf-8)

Install a nerd-font

Make sure Vim uses that nerd font by either:
a. Setting guifont to the name of the nerd-font (e.g.: set guifont=JetBrainMono\ NFM:h9:cAINSI) if you are using gVim. More on that with the following answer: How can I setup a nerd font
b. Make sure your terminal program is using that nerd font.

Install vim-devicons


